Instrumentation tests can't find node tagged with string for test in Android
I'm trying to test a composable using .testTag that sits at the leaf level of the tree given the Composables call structure. The code is in the style of:
Top level Composable
@Composable
fun TopLevelComposable() {
    AComposable()
}

Child composable
@Composable
fun AComposable() {
    LeafComposable()
}

Leaf Composable
@Composable
fun LeafComposable() {
    Text(text = "stringOfText", modifier = Modifier.testTag("Text of AComposable"))
}

MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    TopLevelComposable()
            }
        }
    }
}

Though, I get an error:
java.lang.AssertionError: Failed: assertExists.
Reason: Expected exactly '1' node but could not find any node that satisfies: (TestTag = 'Text of AComposable')
However, the unmerged tree contains '1' node that matches. Are you missing `useUnmergedNode = true` in your finder?


Question
How can I enable androidTest to accept nested .testTag using Composables?

I don't see where you're calling .assertExists() in your example, but the error message has a helpful suggestion. In your instrumented test, add useUnmergedTree = true like so:
    composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("Text of AComposable", useUnmergedTree = true)
        .assertExists()
        .assertIsDisplayed()

